# SQL One result per match

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I've created a query that gives prices for every product ordered by creation date.

What I now need is to only return **one** row per product, i.e. one price per product.

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.price, p.creation_date
FROM PRICE p
INNER JOIN PRODUCT pr
ON p.product_id = pr.product_id 
AND p.filter_id = 3 
AND (p.store_id IN (1,2,3,4) OR p.price_type = 'A')
ORDER BY p.creation_date DESC
```

Currently this query returns several prices per product, since several match, but I only want the newest one of those. The ORDER BY p.creation_date DESC gives the price I want as the first in the list, I want that first entry to be the only result for that product.

I've tried rownum = 1, but that only gives one result for the whole query. 
Please note that this is an **Oracle Database**, so as far as I know TOP does **not** work, same goes for LIMIT.

I've treid googling it, but I can't find examples showing exactly this issue.

**I forgot to mention: There are some prices which have the same creation date for the same product, so there has to be a limit of only giving the first entry for those too**

Comment: you want the highest price is it??

Comment: No, I want the newest price, so when ordered by p.creation_date DESC I want the first one of those.

Comment: Try using something like this, [ROWNUM](http://www.club-oracle.com/forums/limit-clause-for-oracle-sql-t637/#post2014), as a replacement for LIMIT

Comment: That only gives one result for the whole query, not one result for each product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the row_numer() windowing function to get only the latest row:

```
select * from (
  SELECT 
    p.product_id, 
    p.price, 
    row_number() over (partition by product_id order by p.creation_date desc) rn,
    p.creation_date
  FROM PRICE p
  INNER JOIN PRODUCT pr
    ON p.product_id = pr.product_id 
    AND p.filter_id = 3 
    AND (p.store_id IN (1,2,3,4) OR p.price_type = 'A') 
) where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this to get the price list for products

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.price ,first_value(p.price) over (partition by product_id
                                            order by  p.creation_date desc) new_price, p.creation_date
    FROM PRICE p
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT pr
    ON p.product_id = pr.product_id 
    AND p.filter_id = 3 
    AND (p.store_id IN (1,2,3,4) OR p.price_type = 'A')
```

Comment: I tried this and I get the same problem: I still get several prices for each product

Comment: you can remove the p.price column. new_price is the latest price.

Comment: Yes, but I still get 3 entries showing the same price for a product, I only want one row per product

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need the join on product, as... you don't use any row of product in your returned rows...

You might try :

```
SELECT p.product_id, MAX(p.price),  p.creation_date
FROM PRICE p
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT pm.product_id, MAX(pm.creation_date)
    FROM PRICE pm
    GROUP BY pm.product_id) most_recent_price
    ON most_recent_price.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE p.filter_id = 3 
AND (p.store_id IN (1,2,3,4) OR p.price_type = 'A')
GROUP BY p.product_id, p.creation_date
```

Comment: When executing this I get a "keyword missing" error after the "as". Any way this does not work in Oracle DBs?

Comment: I removed the "as" and that worked, but I still get several results per product (they have the same creation date, so it doesn't matter which one of them I take, but I still only need one)

Comment: @kajafls oh, that's another problem then. All prices has the same date for one product, or not always ?

Comment: No, the prices can have different dates or the same, it varies. Right now almost all prices have the same date since they were all put in the database at the same time, but in the future they will vary.

Comment: @kajafls ok, so see edit (I used MAX, you can use MIN or whatever), assuming a product can't have different prices with the same "creation_date" and the same "price".